# Ionic-angular - Routing is not working properly when I have multiple nested routes

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-routing, angular8, router-outlet

I have two pages, Items & Users. Inside Items page I have child routes, add / edit/ delete. Inside Users page I have few child routes, add/ delete. So that makes routing structure something like below.

app-routing.module.ts

```
 {
    path: "users",
    loadChildren: "./users/users.module#UsersPageModule",

  },
  {
    path: "items",
    loadChildren: "./items/items.module#ItemsPageModule"
  }
```

users.module.ts

```
{
    path: "",
    component: UsersPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: "add",
        component: EditUserComponent
      },
      {
        path: "",
        component: UserListComponent,
        pathMatch: "full"
      }
    ]
  }
```

items.module.ts

```
{
    path: "",
    component: ItemsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: "additem",
        component: ItemDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: "",
        component: ItemListComponent,
        pathMatch: "full"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Problem: 
After the application is loaded, if I switch between paths within same page everything works fine but as soon as I visit another page & again come back to the previous page and try to navigate it does not work.

Eg. First I visit /items then /items/add again /items/. Here everything works. The issue starts when I visit /users and again go back to /items. So at this point item page loads fine which is tied to /items. But if I try to navigate /items/add. Nothing seems to happen on UI.

I turned on tracing for routes and found that it shows `Router Event: NavigationEnd`, any clue why this is happening?

Here is the github sample project link: https://github.com/Dhananjay-J-P/ionic-routing-issue.git.

Answer (score 0):

can you show us how are you writing navigation links in your html file ?

It can be like this.

```html
<a [routerLink]="['users']">users</a>
<a [routerLink]="['items']">items</a>
```

Comment: I tried both by using routerLink as well as using router. Currently, I am using `this.router.navigate(["add"], { relativeTo: this.route });` also tried by giving . absolute path `this.router.navigateByUrl("/items/additem");`